# knockoutjs container less template inside SELECT, foreach OPTION not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, template-engine

I have an quiz/survey application and I'm having problems populating a dropdown list using knockoutjs.

Please check this fiddle with Firefox (or Chrome), then try it with Internet Explorer 9 (or IE8, or IE7... knockout says to be compatible from IE6+ but obviously IE gives some problems in my scenario).

In Firefox and Chrome **[my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/firepol/n93Bv/)** works , but not with Internet Explorer. See in thab 1, last question "Where do you live?" and in tab 2, "Favorite sport?". The dropdown is not populated in IE.

I suspect that something is not working well with $parent, or $parent.ParticipantAnswer == null is not understood by IE. I tried to debug but obviously didn't find the cause, so here I am.

In both tab1 and tab2, the options are not populated, so here the code where these 2 templates are called:

```
<!-- ko if: AnswerTypeId == 2 -->
<select data-bind="attr: { name: Id, id: 'answerq' + Id }">
<option value="0"></option>
<!-- ko template: { name: 'option-template', foreach: Answers } -->                                                        
<!-- /ko -->
</select>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: AnswerTypeId == 6 -->
<select data-bind="attr: { name: Id, id: 'answerq' + Id }">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'location-template', foreach: Answers } -->                                                        
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And here the 2 templates:

```
<script type="text/html" id="option-template">

    <!-- ko if: $parent.ParticipantAnswer != null && $parent.ParticipantAnswer.AnswerId == $data.Id -->
    <option data-bind="text: Description, attr: { value: Id, selected: 'selected' }"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: ($parent.ParticipantAnswer == null || $parent.ParticipantAnswer.AnswerId != $data.Id) -->
    <option data-bind="text: Description, attr: { value: Id }"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->

</script>

<script type="text/html" id="location-template">

    <!-- ko if: $parent.ParticipantAnswer != null && $parent.ParticipantAnswer.AnswerInt == $data.Id -->
    <option data-bind="text: Description, attr: { value: Id, selected: 'selected' }"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: ($parent.ParticipantAnswer == null || $parent.ParticipantAnswer.AnswerInt != $data.Id) -->
    <option data-bind="text: Description, attr: { value: Id }"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->              

</script>
```

I was thinking that a container less template would create problems, but [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/w8wdp/) works on both Firefox and IE.

I really have no idea why it doesn't work with IE, I'm asking here for a valid fix and maybe an explanation of the cause, so we all can learn from it ;) Thank you.

Comment: as I specified in my question: IE9 and IE8 (and IE7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, containerless bindings work fine in Internet Explorer.  However, IE (at least before 10) strips comments in certain scenarios like inside of `select` elements.

So, KO never sees the comments or has a chance to process them. One of your best bets is to use the `repeat` binding: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat.  This will basically let you do a `foreach` by attaching to the element to be repeated rather than a container.

Comment: Thank you, knockout-repeat is already making me breathe again. In my ko if: AnswerTypeId == 6, after option 0, instead of calling the location-template I did like this: <option data-bind="repeat: { foreach: Answers, item: '$loc' }" data-repeat-bind="text: $loc().Description"></option> See: http://jsfiddle.net/firepol/n93Bv/7/ . How can I do a "if" check like $parent.ParticipantAnswer.AnswerInt != $data.Id so I can add the attribute selected="selected" for the option that was chosen by the user? Thanks for letting me know... even better with an update in the jsfiddle code.

Comment: @firepol Add this binding to your options: `attr: { selected: ParticipantAnswer.AnswerInt == $loc().Id }`. http://jsfiddle.net/n93Bv/8/

Comment: @Micheal Best: it worked, thank you! I also updated my jsfiddle at  http://jsfiddle.net/n93Bv/9/ . Added extra check (in case ParticipantAnswer is null): attr: { selected: (ParticipantAnswer != null && ParticipantAnswer.AnswerInt == $loc().Id) } . RP Niemeyer: thanks a bunch for recommending me knockout-repeat and double thanks to Micheal Best for developing knockout-repeat (cool stuff! This slution saved me from a big pain with IE)