# Knockout JS & IE functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to create a select dropdown with a blank option at the top. It works fine in Chrome but not in IE (using IE 9). Something is wrong with this section:

```
<!-- ko 'if': $data === 'Blank' -->
<option data-bind="text: '', value: $data"></option>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko 'if': $data !== 'Blank' -->        
<option data-bind="text: $data, value: $data"></option>                
<!-- /ko -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYjyJ/2/

How can I get it to work in IE as it does in Chrome?
Hope the jsFiddle is enough to see what I am trying to accomplish.
I will add more info if required.
Thanks
Jason

Comment: What do you mean on that it is not working in IE9? What is error what you get or what is the problem what you see?

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383680/knockoutjs-container-less-template-inside-select-foreach-option-not-working-wit/18402603#18402603. Basically, IE strips those comments and KO never sees them.

Comment: @nemesv - I was hoping the jsfiddle would demonstrate the problem I was having, a picture paints a thousand words and all that, thanks for looking anyway

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the vitual elements work without passing the binding names as strings.

```
<!-- ko if: $data === 'Blank' -->
<option data-bind="text: '', value: $data"></option>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $data !== 'Blank' -->        
<option data-bind="text: $data, value: $data"></option>                
<!-- /ko -->
```

But more generally:

- if `'Blank'` denotes a default value you should think about using the [`optionsCaption` binding parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters).
- if it does not, the best way would be to solve it in the view model, not in the binding.

  ```
  function Option(text) {
      this.text = text;
      this.displayText = ko.computed(function () {
          return (this.text === 'Blank') ? '' : this.text;
      });
  }

  function ViewModel() {
      this.options = ko.utils.arrayMap(["Blank", "a", "b"], function (text) {
          return new Option(text);
      });
  }
  ```

  and

  ```
  <option data-bind="text: displayText, value: text" />
  ```

  This way you would end up with clean mark-up that does not rely on virtual elements.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went for a template solution:

```
<select id="jq-my-id" data-bind="template: { name: aoiTemplate, foreach: aoiTypes },value: aoi">
</select>
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/html" id="group-aoi-template">
<optgroup data-bind="attr: {'label': $data}, foreach: getAoisFor($data)">        
    <option data-bind="text: $data.text, value: $data.code"></option>        
</optgroup>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="blank-template">
    <option data-bind="text: '', value: $data.code"></option>
</script>
```

And in my view model to select the correct template:

```
self.aoiTemplate = function (aoiType) {
    return aoiType !== 'Blank' ? 'group-aoi-template' : 'blank-template';
};
```

Because of the optgroup I couldn't use the optionsCaption binding.